# Tooltip should not display on MouseHover

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox with an associated tooltip that I want to show when the picturebox is clicked, but not when the mouse is hovered over it. I tried creating an empty MouseHover event for the picturebox, but the tooltip is still displayed:

```
    private void pictureBox3_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int durationMilliseconds = 30000;
        toolTip1.Show(toolTip1.GetToolTip(pictureBox3), pictureBox3, durationMilliseconds);
    }
```

What can I do so that the tooltip is not displayed on MouseHover?

Comment: Events can have multiple methods tied to them. Try adding `e.Handled =true` to the hover event. That way the event is marked as handled and subsequent methods on that event are not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set a tooltip for pictureBox3 (remove it). Just show one:

```
// On class scope to have access from MouseEnter
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();

private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int durationMilliseconds = 30000;        
    tt.IsBalloon = true;
    tt.InitialDelay = 0;
    tt.Show("tooltip text", pictureBox3, durationMilliseconds);
}
```

To prevent the tooltip to be set permantly add an event handler to the picturebox for `MouseEnter`:

```
private void pictureBox3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     tt.RemoveAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After a click the hover event is active again though. (I have removed the original tooltip)

Comment: I have added a way to prevent this

Comment: Thanks again for your help!